# Syntax Error Creating Identity/Primary Key Column on Azure through SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I came across an syntax error message when I tried creating a table in [sql-azure](/questions/tagged/sql-azure) through a local SSMS connection. This error does not occur if I run the same query on a local host DB instead of my azure connection.

```
Create table Portfolio_Company_Financials 
(
PCF_ID int not null identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
CompanyID int,
ReportingDate date,
Revenue float,
)
```

Above throws the error:

> Parse error at line: 3, column: 21: Incorrect syntax near 'identity'

It will execute when I comment out identity(1,1) and over. It has the same issue with with using using only primary:

`...PCF_ID int not null PRIMARY KEY,...`

Additionally it looks like I cannot manually change column properties through the SSMS object explorer and can only refresh/delete when right clicking to the column.

It looks like a SSMS/permissions/azure issue? Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you try to create the table in Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse.  Azure SQL Data Warehouse does not yet support primary keys and the identity property.  You can confirm your version with the following sql:

select @@version

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-overview